# Three issues (possibly) related to read-only filesystem

Tags: usb, firefox, downloads, wget, read-only

Previously, I had a flash drive full of both Ubuntu images and other OSs. I **moved** them (didn't copy them) from that flash drive to another with more storage space. In the process, something went wrong and I ended up having to reformat both drives. I lost all of my OSs that I've spent months collecting and trying (I'm still new to Linux).

Now, I'm trying to re-download the Ubuntu images I had, however, when I click download on the [website](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/contribute?version=17.04&architecture=amd64), nothing happens. When I click `download now` on the [next page](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?country=US&version=17.04&architecture=amd64) *(if you click this, you'll probably be prompted to save the .iso)*, nothing happens either.

I don't know if this is an issue with Firefox or if my entire system is mounted read-only.

---

When I use `wget` to download the .iso, it says:

```
Cannot write to ‘ubuntu-17.04-desktop-amd64.iso’ (Read-only file system).
```

I don't know if this is my installation of Ubuntu or the flash drive that's mounted read-only.

---

I also can't use `isohybrid` to convert the two .iso files I do have of Manjaro and Gecko Linux because `(Read-only file system)` is output again.

---

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'd really rather not have to format my USB stick ***again*** to download them with a Windows computer that I'd have to wait to use at the college.

---

Outputs

`mount`

```
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=933748k,nr_inodes=233437,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=191320k,mode=755)
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=37,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=12262)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/user/120 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=191316k,mode=700,uid=120,gid=127)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=191316k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
```

---

Comment: Running the "mount" command to see how it's mounted would be a good start.

Comment: @barrycarter To see how what's mounted? I ran `mount` and I don't recognise anything of whatever was output. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: You could include the output above-- I don't think it'll show anything that's dangerous to share.

Comment: @barrycarter I added it.

Comment: I'm guessing `/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)` is your USB drive. As mount notes, the drive was automatically remounted in readonly (ro) mode because there were errors when you tried to mount it readwrite (rw). Try unmounting and remounting and see what errors you get.

Comment: @barrycarter Wouldn't `/dev/sda1` be a local hard drive?

Comment: @barrycarter Yeah. `/dev/sda1` is my hard drive. To remount that, would I have to reboot my computer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65735/discussion-between-barrycarter-and-amolith).